# Store Entity Framework - Code First Data Annotations in XML

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

Is there a ready-made solution to store Model Data Annotations in a separate XML file? Easier to change etc ...

Comment: It may look easy but maintaining that would be difficult

Comment: It almost seems contrary to model-first, with it's own XML format. Not that I care for model-first.